# How can I show a snackbar after navigator.pop(context) in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, navigator, snackbar

We need close one screen and open a second screen. And show snackbar on the second screen from first screen.

I tried to use `Navigator.push`, but this screen is already open and we have this error

> Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of Snackbar i would suggest you to use Flushbar plugin for flutter it is easy to use and it'll take care of everything and u can customize it to a great extent .
Snackbar needs a scaffold ancestor to work but
Flushbar doesn't and it takes care of all the extra stuff itself and provides with ton of cool features.

[Flushbar Plugin here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flushbar)

Comment: Thank you! And I don't find how we can close flushbar after user press button "OK" on this bar. Maybe you know?

Comment: flushbar has a function _.dismiss()_ .  when you press ok call a function in that function do this   `flushbar.dismiss()`;

Comment: Yes, I try it. But it doesn't work(
And I don't understand why.

Comment: `flushbar = Flushbar(
 title: "Some",
 message: "text",
 duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
 mainButton: FlatButton(
  onPressed: (){
   flushbar.dismiss();
  },
  child: Text(
   "OK"
  ),
 ),
)..show(context);`

Comment: i&#39;ld have to try it myself before i could tell u why it isn&#39;t working. i was using swipe to dismiss rather than any button action.

Comment: Same problem here. Need something to get rid of bug

Comment: @EmilyHarkness Better use `Navigator.pop(context)`, since **FlushBar** works by pushing a new route on top of the existing ones (as described in the documentation)...

Comment: Flushbar is discontinued, any thoughts on where to go now?

Comment: We cannot use Flushbar because it has been discontinued. https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar

Comment: another one?
https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understand 100% the use case you have but by returning results from screens and passing arguments to new routes, you can work around basically any scenario.

Let's take an example. A is the original screen, then you push screen B. Now you see B, perform some action there, pop it, you get back to screen A and you want to display a snackbar.

When you `pop`, you can return a result and handle that result from the "parent" screen as described in the ["Return data from a screen"](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data) cookbook.

When you receive a result, you can either show a snackbar notification, or alternatively (in case there is a third screen), you can [pass that result to another screen as argument](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).

Comment: wish you answer selected instead solution using library/package

Comment: I'm getting the following error using this solution: `Scaffold.geometryOf() must only be accessed during the paint phase.`

Answer (score 1):

Please read this [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data) by Flutter that answers your question with example.

What you have to do is, when you are going to `Navigator.pop` you can pass a message and based on that message you can show `SnackBar` in the previous screen where you did `Navigator.push`

So when you pop do something like this:

```
Navigator.pop(context, 'Yes');
Navigator.pop(context, 'No');
```

Here, you are passing a message and based on this message you can show the Snackbar in the previous screen where you pushed like this:

```
final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SelectionScreen()),
  );

  // After the Selection Screen returns a result, hide any previous snackbars
  // and show the new result.
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
    ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
    ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('$result')));
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error using this solution: `Scaffold.geometryOf() must only be accessed during the paint phase.`

Comment: Now I just use BloC pattern. It's better and easy this way. Back when I posted the solution, that used to work fine. But maybe after Dart 3 it changed. Try a simple cubit and listen to a snackbar state to be emitted by the cubit using BloC pattern. Flutter BloC library is awesome. It's much fun and easy.

Comment: We need to add another check before using context `if(!context.mounted) return;`. However doing so still give some error at least in context of using chrome as device.. any help

Answer (score 0):

```
showSubmitRequestSnackBar(BuildContext context) async {

  Flushbar(
    flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
    message: "Request Successfully Saved",
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.info_outline,
      size: 28.0,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    leftBarIndicatorColor: Colors.red,

  )
    ..show(context).then((r)=> Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListPage(""))));
}
```

Comment: This shows the Flushbar after it is dismissed (5 seconds later in this case), which is not what you want in most (if not all cases).

Comment: We cannot use Flushbar because it has been discontinued. https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar

Answer (score 0):

**Screen A**

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => BScreen(
      callbackFunction: (String resMessage){
        print(resMessage);
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

**Screen B**

```
class BScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function callbackFunction;

  BScreen({required this.callbackFunction});

  @override
  _BScreenState createState() => _BScreenState();
}


class _BScreenState extends State<BScreen> {
  // 
  _performTask(){
    // add your task here
    // ..........
    String msg = 'Task has been added';
    widget.callbackFunction(msg);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _performTask();
          },
          child: Text('Click Here'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This solution worked for me. Happy to help others :) Thanks for asking this question.