# How to show a Snackbar or bottom sheet when the app opens in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

So I have a requirement, where I need to show the `Snackbar` just when the application starts, but when I try to do it, it gives me context error. How can I know that my Widget tree has been built and use the context to display the `Snackbar`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Welcome User')));
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include a snippet of code that reproduces the problem you are having

Comment: See the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948168/how-to-create-toast-in-flutter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a [GlobalKey](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) of type [ScaffoldState](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ScaffoldState-class.html) to make sure you target the right Scaffold to show a SnackBar on.

Set your target Scaffold's key to the key you have created.

In your initState() function use [WidgetsBinding](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBinding-class.html) class and [addPostFrameCallback](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) to execute your code when the layout is built. Show your SnackBar in the call back.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Welcome User'))));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, that worked! Could you tell me what this function does and are there similar functions to listen to WidgetTree state.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `GlobalKey`, `Builder` or any typical stuff like that. Simply use `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar()`.

**Full code:**

```dart
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Hi'));
    Future(() => ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold();
}
```

Comment: It would also be worth mentioning that this is a breaking change API, that isn't available on the Stable channel yet. It's most likely on the Master channel.

Comment: How can you show this every-time the app come to the foreground? Currently, it will only show when the page rebuild.. The selected page is not rebuild if the app comes to the foreground.