# Notification floating popup menu

Tags: flutter

i'm re-building an app already done in Cordova with HTML5, using Flutter.

I need a plugin or a Widget that emulate the popup menu of the notification without change routes.

Is there anything?

I'll provide a screenshot:

[notification menu](http://www.svsoftwares.org/notification.jpg)

Comment: Maybe a Toast relates here - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948168/how-to-create-toast-in-flutter

Comment: @StefanoV827 the image link is broken consider uploading the image to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Dialog class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html)

Here is an example of the AlertDialog

```
Future<void> _neverSatisfied() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Rewind and remember'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('You will never be satisfied.'),
              Text('You\’re like me. I’m never satisfied.'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Regret'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Alternatively you can use the [Stack class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) for greater flexibility

```
SizedBox(
      width: 250,
      height: 250,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: <Color>[
                  Colors.black.withAlpha(0),
                  Colors.black12,
                  Colors.black45
                ],
              ),
            ),
            child: Text(
              "Foreground Text",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Correct, you can use the Stack widget if you want more control. Updated answer with their example

Comment: I read too late sorry. 
I posted the final code.

Do you know how to catch the back button event?

Comment: No probs. You'll need to use the WillPopScope class - see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918186/469335

Answer (score 0):

At the end i used Stacks.
I read the edited answer too late, but the result is the same.

Here the prototype class for everyone:

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

        class MenuTendina extends StatefulWidget {

          final double opacita;
          final double altezza;
          final Widget child;
          final Widget notifiche;


          MenuTendina({Key key, @required this.child, @required this.notifiche, @required this.opacita, @required this.altezza}) : super(key:key);

          @override
          _MenuTendinaState createState() => _MenuTendinaState();

        }

        class _MenuTendinaState extends State<MenuTendina> {

          Widget child;
          Widget notifiche;
          double opacita;
          double altezza;
          bool mostraTendina = true;

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
            this.child,
                Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: (this.mostraTendina) ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height : 0.0,
                    child: Opacity(
                        opacity: this.opacita,
                        child: Container(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  this.opacita = 0.0;
                                  this.altezza = 0.0;
                                  this.mostraTendina = false;
                                });
                              },
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                AnimatedContainer(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                        offset: Offset(0, -5),
                        spreadRadius: 0.0,
                        blurRadius: 20
                    )],
                  ),
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: this.altezza,
                  child: this.notifiche,
                )
              ],
            );
          }


        }
```

The only problem now is how to catch the backbutton event, because usually when the users see the notification, they press the back button to hide them...